# Criar banner interativo personalizado HTML estilo hover overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Olá, gostaria de criar um banner no estilo hover overlay semelhante ao que se encontra neste site:
http://www.gruporedservicos.com.br/

[image: Banner interativo]

Basicamente, ao passar o mouse por cima da imagem, a camada onde está escrito "Experiencia" se move, e ao retirar o mouse de cima da imagem, ela volta ao ponto de origem.

Quebrei a cabeça tentando fazer algo semelhante. Sei que o site roda wordpress, então caso isso seja um plugin, aceito nomes.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo usando apenas `css`, ao passar o mouse em cima o tamanho da `div` filha será 100% da `div` pai

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.imagem {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.texto {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_960_720.png" alt="Avatar" class="imagem">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="texto">Texto aqui</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! mas como fazer pra aparecer apenas um titulo enquanto o hover nao é executado? como no site citado acima. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: AI vai da sua criatividade, eu não posso fazer por você